# how to correct setOnItemClickListener?

Tags: java, android, listview, listactivity, onclicklistener

i add the setOnItemClickListener to this code and have Search Filter, when i click list item instead of opening a new activity , i  get force close !!!
every thing is work fine but not open the listitem activity !
where is my code wrong ?

My code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// List view
private ListView lv;

// Listview Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;


// ArrayList for Listview
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      // Listview Data
      String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE","iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800","Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};



     lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
     inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

     // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);


     lv.setAdapter(adapter);

 //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // listening to single list item on click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

          // selected item 
          String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

          // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
          // sending data to new activity
          i.putExtra("product", product);
          startActivity(i);

      }
    });
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
    });
    }

 }
```

Comment: What is the exception in Logcat.., better to post it

Comment: please use `yourclassname.this` as context rather than `getApplicationContext()` for intents;

Comment: No, `getApplicationContext` works perfect with Intents.

Comment: Is the second activity extending activity and registered in the manifest?

Comment: did u declare SingleListItem.class in your mainfeast file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without log it is hard to tell, but 2 things are possible:
1) your view is not a TextView and so you get ClassCastException
2) activity SingleListItem is not declared in the manifest

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems here `String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();`

Get the value by `position`

i.e. `String product =  products[position];`